# Proxmox Under VMware Fusion: Proxmox halts the guest CPU

Tags: proxmox, fusion

I am attempting to do some prototyping/proof of concept work with proxmox. I created a VMWare Fusion VM with two cores (with hypervisor enabled), 8GB of RAM, two 40GB drives, and a bridged network adapter.

Installed Proxmox 8.1.3 with no hitch. System boots and I can access the web control panel.

Now the rub: after the system has been up for a few minutes, I get an error dialog from Fusion stating

> The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system.

Initial searches indicate that this might be a kernel panic, something beyond my ken.

Has anyone else seen this?
Is running Proxmox under Fusion, even for PoC, even possible?
Suggestions?

TIA,
Dave